# FullCalendar - Getting both HTML and arg in eventContent

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to create a custom event tile in FullCalendar. I want to show the title on one line and an extendedProps entry on the next one. Now I found 2 ways to achieve either HTML or using args:

```
eventContent:  (arg) => ( arg.event.title + ' ' + arg.event.extendedProps.places + ' Places')
```

or

```
eventContent: { html: 'Title <br> places'}
```

What I am wondering is if there is a way to use both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject into the HTML with properties of the event as follows:

```
eventContent: function(eventInfo) { return { html: eventInfo.event.title + "<br> " + eventInfo.event.extendedProps.places + " Places" } }
```